# I need help finding mathematical expressions of logic gates

Tags: math, logic, computer-science, logical-operators, algebra

My problem is super niche, but I need help finding ways to express logic gates with simple mathematical expressions. I already have Not, And, & Xor, but I can't figure out Or. And is y=a*b, Not is y=|a-1|, and Xor is y=|a-b|. The inputs, a & b, can only be 0 or 1. The output, y, can also only be 0 or 1.

I have tried many different equations, and the closest I've gotten is a+b/a+b, but, if both a & b are 0, it gives an error instead of 0.

Comment: `y = a + b - a * b`?

Comment: Note that simply `Not(a) = 1 - a`.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It says I can't delete it because people have taken time to investigate it. I'm sorry for not having my question be about programming, but I assumed that math was close enough to programming that I could ask this here. I will use the links provided in the future. I'm sorry for any trouble I've caused. It will not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max`:

```
x or y = max(x, y)
```

If you don't like max, remember that max and absolute value can easily be expressed using each other:

```
|a| = max(a, -a)
max(a, b) = (a+b)/2 + |b-a|/2
```

Note that this formula for `max(a,b)` might look complicated and hard to remember if you think of it only in terms of algebra; but if you think in terms of geometry then it becomes very simple. `(a+b)/2` is the middle point of segment `[a,b]` and `|b-a|/2` is the vector that goes from this middle point towards the maximum of the two points.

Alternatively, you can think of "or" as a union of events, and "and" as an intersection of events, and use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to express "or" using "and":

```
x or y = x + y - x * y
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have `not` and `and`.

or(a, b) =  not (and(not(a), not(b)))

by deMorgan's law.